# Scaling plots in the terminal nodes of ctree graph

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I am trying to scale the plots that appear in the terminal nodes of a ctree. I have tried using the yscale parameter but this just results plots that extend beyond the plotting window

For example: Here is a ctree for two exponential distributions

```
set.seed(1)    
classA <-data.frame(class = "a", val = round(rexp(500, rate = 0.2),0))
classB <-data.frame(class = "b", val = round(rexp(500, rate = 0.05),0))

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(classA,classB))

ct = ctree(val~., data = df)
plot(ct)
```

Now if I try to scale the y axis of the plots from 0 to 70 to zoom in on the box plots and cut-off the outliers, I can use:

```
plot(ct,terminal_panel = node_boxplot(ct,yscale =c(0,70)))
```

This works to scale the y axis, but now the plot extends beyond the plotting box.

Sorry I would show images, but don't have enough privileges on stackoverflow yet.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: In an example like this it would be better to log-transform the response because then the association tests employed in `ctree()` will have more power to detect differences for splitting in the tree. Possibly some small continuity correction might help if there are exact zeros.

But, of course, the problem of the proper scaling in the terminal nodes is separate from this. The reason was that the viewports for the terminal nodes were not set to `clip = TRUE` and hence didn't clip graphical elements outside the viewport region.

I've just fixed this problem in the `partykit` package on R-Forge. A new CRAN release is not scheduled yet but you can either check out the partykit-SVN from R-Forge or just download the current [partykit/R/plot.R](https://R-Forge.R-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/partykit/R/plot.R?revision=724&root=partykit) source code.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks Achim! I will let you know when I try the new source code. I realize my example was somewhat silly, I just wanted to quickly show the lack of clipping function. Thank you:)

Comment: The new fixed version of the `partykit` package has been released to CRAN now (1.0-2). If you use that, your example works as desired.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this. I downloaded and tried the new version of partykit. I can now scale the y axis using `plot(ct,terminal_panel = node_boxplot(ct,yscale =c(0,70)))`. However, I have a new problem with partykit not showing the y axis tic labels. I posted this problem as a new thread here: [link to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834052/partykit-ctree-formating-x-and-y-axis-labels) Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The new version (1.0-4) of the partykit package on CRAN fixes the problem with the tick marks while preserving the clipping of the plotting region. So with that version of the package both of your requests should be addressed.