# partykit ctree formating x and y axis labels

Tags: r, party

My problem is the newest version of the partykit package seems to remove all x and y axis tics and labels from ctree plots.

```
install.package("partykit")
library(partykit)

irisct <- ctree(Species ~ .,data = iris)
plot(irisct)
```

See ... no x or y labels in the terminal nodes!

I want the plots to look like they do in the party package:

```
detach("package:partykit", unload=TRUE)
library(party)

irisct <- ctree(Species ~ .,data = iris)
plot(irisct)
```

From what I have seen online partykit should be able to recreate all party plots and more. Hopefully the answer to this question is easy, because I do need to take advantage of some of the formatting features I have seen described for partykit!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: It was a bug that I introduced when enabling clipping for the plotting regions. And in some circumstances this also clipped the axes labels. Version 1.0-4 of the partykit package fixes the problem and is already available on the CRAN master server at http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=partykit.

Comment: OK, good, thanks for the feedback. Please also mark this as resolved here on SO.